# How to change the Locale time into Banana TimePicker Panel

Tags: solr, banana

Let's say I want to show in a Banana TimePicker Panel exactly the Locale time which is present into the Solr query results, let's say times with GMT+2. But the problem is that Banana is always showing the GMT+0 time (solr result times minus 2 hours).

So the only workaround I found was to change my Locale directly from the client side, that's sad...

Does anyone has a solution by editing directly the file 'module.js' ?

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Solr always store dates in ISO8601 format which is GMT+00. In Histogram panel, Time Correction setting specifies how time is calculated: browser displays values in local (client) time whereas utc keeps time as is, i.e. value stored in Solr.

Comment: Thank's a lot Aadel, great, it works really well.